# Device connected, but 'IBMIoT: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized' message keeps popping up

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot

I am experimenting with IoT services in IBM Bluemix, attending [a running MOOC at Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/developer-iot). I have set up my trial account and successfully registered some devices. I am testing the connectivity between Bluemix and my Raspberry Pi with the following simple Node-RED flow in Bluemix:

[Node-RED flow @ Bluemix[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j6UG.png)

where `normal` and `alert` are simple injection nodes of the respective strings, the `format message` node is similarly simple (returns `msg`, where `msg.payload = {'a' : {'indicator' : msg.payload}};`, and the `IBM IoT` node is as follows:

[image]

The senseHAT device is registered and successfully connected to Bluemix, as apparent from the Watson IoT Platform dashboard:

[image]

From the Raspberry side, I have set the following simple flow to catch the 'commands' (`normal` and `alert`) issued in Bluemix:

[Node-RED flow @ Raspberry Pi[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHAEG.png)

with the `all commands` node being as follows:

[image]

Now, although the 'commands' `normal` and `alert` pass through from Bluemix to my Raspberry, I keep on getting the subject error message, as shown below (notice the time stamps):

[image]

and a similar error message is logged in the Node-RED console (once per minute):

```
Connection Error :: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized
9 Jun 19:41:19 - [error] IBMIoT: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized
Iotfclient is offline. Retrying connection
Connection was closed.
```

I wonder how it is possible, on the one hand to have the 'commands' passed through, while on the other hand to get at error message per minute claiming that I am not connected since my device is not authorized.

Any ideas?

On a side note (and as possibly useful additional info):

1. pressing 'Refresh' in the Watson IoT Platform dashboard, the senseHAT device appears disconnected; refreshing the whole page (ie from the browser), it appears again connected
2. no matter what I have tried, I cannot connect the other two devices shown above (`b827eb0a0ee8` and `b827eb5f5bbd`) - I even tried deleting and re-registering them again in Bluemix...

Comment: Re your side notes:


1. this is a known issue and fix is in plan


2. b827eb0a0ee8 is a device but you are using a gateway client ID when trying to connect (**g**:e7u2kv:raspberry:b827eb0a0ee8 should be **d**:e7u2kv:raspberry:b827eb0a0ee8, similarly, b827eb5f5bbd is a gateway but you are using a device client ID (**d**:e7u2kv:raspberryGW:b827eb5f5bbd should be **g**:e7u2kv:raspberryGW:b827eb5f5bbd)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the cause of this could be the mix up of gateways and devices as per my previous comment.  From the logs it looks like you have changed the types of the device IDs between gateway and device, and in some cases a device with id b827eb0a0ee8 has connected as a gateway (shown as just a device in your screen shot) and subsequently been disconnected because it attempts something unauthorised (probably attempting to connect an unregistered device; ie the client ID mix up issue).

Auto registration of devices is temporarily disabled and so if a device does not exist (because the client ID is wrong) then the gateway device will be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted Paul's answer as correct, as it helped me figure out what goes on, but it is rather cryptic. Here is what exactly is happening, along with a remedy.

If (even **accidentally**) you try to erroneously connect a device as a gateway (or vice versa), the whole thing gets messed up...:

1. You cannot re-connect the device/gateway, even if you go back and correct the credentials (i.e. your device/gateway is doomed...)
2. Once such a thing (accident...) has happened, **all** your other registered devices, although they can be successfully connected to Bluemix, give the error message I have described in my question above (including the status in the Node-RED console, forever reporting `Connection was closed`.
3. Restarting your Bluemix app has no effect

So, once such a mistake/accident has happened for whatever reason, the **remedy** is to stop and start again your local Node-RED service (i.e. in my case the one running in my Raspberry Pi).

I hope this helps for future improvements of the platform - it is certainly an unexpected behavior.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the issue is that the IoT node in Node Red is not updating the fixed credentials correctly and needs to be restarted in order to get the config updated ?

Comment: Sounds plausible - but again, why such behavior with the other devices??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior. Just restarting the local Node-RED didn't help. After restart, I deleted the wiotp-credentials node, recreated it , deployed the flow, and worked finally my gateway connected.