# Error: Connection refused: Not authorized on debug view on IBM Bluemix

Tags: arduino, ibm-cloud, esp8266, node-red, watson-iot

I am trying to do some experiments with IBM Bluemix platform for my IOT application. I am able to publish the events which are logging well also on Bluemix. I have checked this thread but didn't work for me [IBM Bluemix: Device connected, but 'IBMIoT: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized' message keeps popping up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731964/ibm-bluemix-device-connected-but-ibmiot-error-connection-refused-not-autho)

[image]

I have added one device on Bluemix, see below snapshot

[image]

I am trying to debug whatever message is being published from my ESP8266 which is connected to the IBM Bluemix

[image]

I am trying to debug this published message in node red debug console, there it is displaying below error:

> msg : string[41]
>   "Error: Connection refused: Not authorized"

[image]

Can anyone help me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Bluemix services only works if your application is bound the IoT Platform service. Maybe it isn't or something up there. I always use API keys instead.  You can generate a pair under Apps in the IoT Platform.

Comment: @amadain How to connect IOT service to my Node-RED ? Here is what my services and cloud foundry apps http://imgur.com/a/2wI6x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Node-RED application should be authenticating with a valid API Key.  Be sure you have the right API credentials and update the ibmiot node choosing API Key from the authentication drop down box and supplying the API Key credentials for your service.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your connection is failing due to authentication error with your API Key  (API key not found in database).  Please confirm you are using valid ClientID and API key for your application.

Comment: This was also mistake I was doing. I was not adding valid API key.